# Как импортировать пакет в зависимости от платформы

Tags: flutter, dart

Друзья! Как импортировать пакет в зависимости от платформы, мне нужно импортировать пакет для загрузки изображений в web версии и android(ios) попробовал такую конструкцию:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Выдает ошибку:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот сам класс:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Может сделать свой враппер и там в зависимости от платформы вызывать тот или иной метод?

Answer (score 1):

Вы все делаете все правильно, но есть одна ошибка: Во всех 3 импортах должна быть одинаковая структура класса и его методов. А как вы будете реализовать методы это на ваше усмотрение.

Вы даже в главном импорте можете реализовать абстракный класс, а в платформенных импортах реализовать его (implements).

[Примеры](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58710226/how-to-import-platform-specific-dependency-in-flutter-dart-combine-web-with-an)